# Red Neuronal tensorflow test accuracy

Tags: python, test, tensorflow, red

tengo unas dudas respecto a Redes Neuronales, si me podrían ayudar por favor.

Realice un modelo de red neuronal que busca predecir una variable de 4 categorías (lo recodifique: 0, 1, 2 y 3) y el resultado fue:

Test Los[0.9032, 3.899]

-Esta bien recodificar la variable dependiente empezando de 0? Vi en internet algunos lo recodifican desde 1

-Para evaluar si un modelo es mejor que otro, es correcto fijarnos en el test loss y accuracy?

-Vi que el test accuracy debe ir de 0-1, sucedería lo mismo cuánto la Target o la variable a predecir tiene varias categorías? El resultado de mi modelo fue 3.899

y... esta bien el categorizar mi variable de esta forma: 0, 1, 2 y 3? empezando de 0 y no de 1

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

El valor de la precisión (accuracy) en un problema de clasificación, ya sea binario o multiclase, siempre debe estar en el rango de 0 a 1. Un valor de precisión mayor a 1 no es posible ni significativo en el contexto de evaluación de modelos de aprendizaje automático.

La precisión se calcula dividiendo el número de predicciones correctas por el número total de ejemplos en el conjunto de prueba. Dado que esta proporción nunca puede ser mayor que 1 (100%), la precisión siempre estará en el rango de 0 a 1.